# How to use CSS3 selectors to ignore IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

In the example below, I want IE8 to show the text in `red`, but `green` for all modern browsers.

I know that IE8 doesn't understand selectors like `:nth-child()`, so I come up with `p:nth-child(odd), p:nth-child(even) {...}` to override the former style.

Is there any more elegant way of doing it? I'm aware of the conditional comment `...[if lte IE 8]...` exists, but that is not what I'm asking in this question.

```css
p {
  color: red;
}

p:nth-child(odd),
p:nth-child(even) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
```

Comment: It's unclear to me why you accepted LGSon's answer. Yes, I do recommend the @media hack when you specifically need to hide from IE8 and not any other version - [even I use it myself](http://novalistic.com/css/frontend.ie.css) - and browser/feature detection is fine if you're using something like Modernizr, but you specifically asked for a selector hack, right?

Comment: @BoltClock I marked that answer only because the [link](http://browserhacks.com/#hack-319658f3c65762a24dc67d5ccf8cd452) posted there, it leads me to find more options easily. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS hacks is maybe not *elegant*, though they still get the job done.

There is a few CSS hacks for IE8, read more at: http://browserhacks.com/

Here is one, using `@media \0screen { ... }`

```css
p {
  color: green;
}

@media \0screen {
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
```

Another using `selector { property: value\9; }`

```css
p {
  color: green;
  color: red\9;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
```

---

A small JS hack is another, if you like script better
`var isIE8 = document.all && !document.addEventListener;`

```js
/*Set html class if IE8*/
(function(d) {
  if (document.all && !document.addEventListener) {
    d.className += ' isIE8';
  }
})(document.documentElement);
```

```css
p {
  color: green;
}

.isIE8 p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of `:nth-child` for targeting browsers is a bad idea.

Especially if that selector is applied to dynamic collection, when you do `container.removeNode(child)` browser will be forced to scan all siblings and recalculate their used styles. Just because you need to target IE8 your doc will be heavier in all other browsers.

I'd suggest to add class to body element (either on server or by JS) , say `.ie8`, and use it in selectors:

```
p {
  color: green;
}

.ie8 p {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can condense `:nth-child(odd), :nth-child(even)` to just `:nth-child(n)`, which is a guaranteed match on all elements except `:root`:

```css
p {
  color: red;
}

p:nth-child(n) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
```

However, IE8 selector hacks typically consist of adding `:root` to the start of each complex selector instead, which has the same effect, even adding the same amount of specificity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library like http://selectivizr.com/ to give IE newer selectors.